# Control how Solrj beans handle null values?

Tags: solr, solrj

With JAXB & JSON both I can get some degree of control over how null values are handled, is there a corresponding feature for Solrj beans (@Field)?

What I'd like is for Solr multivalued fields to read back as an empty (size() == 0) List rather than null.

TIA

Comment: did you consider adding a default value for that field instead? is a feasible option for your scenario?

Comment: These particular fields (List<String>) are calculated, and are potentially a list.size(0) which appears to be stored as a null.

It seems to be a weakness in Solrj beans that this case cannot be handled declaratively.